# how to make it so that usb tethering uses cellular data instead of hotspot

Tags: samsung

I'm used to my old phone using cellular data when using USB tethering but my new phone uses hotspot data.
is there a way to make it use cellular instead?

Comment: Turn off wifi when using usb tethering, It won't use wifi but mobile data.